# Problems installing a Debian package (.deb) using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to install a Debian package in several remote servers using Ansible. The package has been uploaded in a folder in the target server. I created an Ansible playbook using the apt module:

```yaml
- name: Installing Agent
  apt:
    deb: /home/administrator/ftp/SentinelAgent_linux_v4_4_2_3.deb
```

During execution I got the following error:

```
TASK [Installing Agent]
***********************************************
fatal: [brw.01.bwt]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to install package: E:Invalid archive member header"}
```

In a different server, I was able to install the package manually using the dpkg command, that tells me there is nothing wrong with the .deb file.

Any clue on why this playbook isn't working would be appreciated. I'm using Ansible version 2.9.6 in an Ubuntu 20.04.1 Virtual Machine.

Comment: Is `xz-utils` installed on the target machine?

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by hedgie in the comments, the package `xz-utils` needs to be installed for Ansible to install .deb packages via the `apt` module. This requirement is described in the [official Ansible documentation for the apt module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-deb). For the `deb` parameter, it says it takes a `string` which is:

> Path to a .deb package on the remote machine.
> If :// in the path, ansible will attempt to download deb before installing. (Version added 2.1)
> Requires the xz-utils package to extract the control file of the deb package to install.

The solution is, before your `apt:` task, add another task:

```yaml
- name: Install prerequisites for Ansible to install .deb via apt module
  apt:
    name:
    - xz-utils
```

Comment: Yes,  xz-utils is pre-installed in all the servers.      $ apt -qq list xz-utils
xz-utils/bionic,now 5.2.2-1.3 amd64 [installed]  However I'm still getting the "invalid archive member header"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the shell module and exute dpkg -i 
Make sure to copy the deb file before you execute the shell
Make sure to grand root access with `become: yes`  and `become_method: sudo`

Comment: There is an apt module made just for that that will manage idempotency for you. Why would you use shell in this case?

Comment: I tested your suggestion using shell and it works! But as Zeitounator said, the rule of thumb on Ansible scripting  would be using modules created for specific tasks first and use the generic shell module if there is no alternative, so I'd try to see if I can manage to make the apt module work. Thanks.